# How do I apply methods from a constructor object to an arbitrary object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a constructor object that has various fields; For a simple example, say

```
function Person(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  etc.
  this.someFunction = function(xxx) {...}
}
```

Now, I have an arbitrary object with an id and name field

```
var somePerson = {id:123, name:"joe"}
```

I would like to inject the data from the somePerson instance into a Person constructor, so I can apply all of the methods from the Person class, but I am confused between apply, call, and bind.

I am aware that I can call a new constructor passing in all of the fields, but there are a lot of fields. Is there any easy way to just endow the somePerson instance with the methods from the Person class?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it wrong, what you are trying to do is :

```
var somePerson = new Person(123, 'joe');
```

then you will be able to write :

```
somePerson.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `Person` instance, there's no need to use `call` or `apply`.

```
var somePerson = {id:123, name:"joe"};
var somePersonInstance = new Person(somePerson.id, somePerson.name);
somePersonInstance.someFunction(xxx);
```

You could have used `call` if the method was *not* inside the constructor, but on the prototype:

```
function Person(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.someFunction = function(xxx) {…};

var somePerson = {id:123, name:"joe"};
Person.prototype.someFunction.call(somePerson, xxx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign()` and assign properties of `somePerson` object to instance of `Person`

```js
function Person(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.someFunction = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var somePerson = {id:123, name:"joe"}
var p = Object.assign(new Person, somePerson)

console.log(p.someFunction())
```

Comment: did you mean var p = Object.assign(new Person(), somePerson)

Comment: You can omit parenthesis if you are not going to supply arguments.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work with constructors that *require* their arguments. I'd recommend to always use a class-specific helper methods, such as `Person.fromJSON` (that knows how/whether to call its constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Sure How's this;

```
function PersonFactory(id, name) {
    return {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        updateName: function(name)  {
            this.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

Some exmaples of it being used.

```
var somePerson = PersonFactory(1, "Luke")

var people = {
    luke: PersonFactory(1, "Luke"),
    will: PersonFactory(2, "Will"),
    smith: PersonFactory(3, "Smith")
}

var persons = [
PersonFactory(1, "Luke"),
PersonFactory(1, "Will"),
PersonFactory(1, "Smith")
]

people.luke.updateName("Harry");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Person` is set up like a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function). You need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate a new copy of `Person`.

```
var joe = new Person(somePerson.id, somePerson.name);
```

Now `joe` will be an instance of `Person`.

```
joe instanceof Person //true
joe.id //123
joe.someFunction //function (xxx) {...}
```